# Is there Partial Formatting for Flutter&Dart in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

I tend to CTRL+S my code quite often so Dart SDK formatter automatically formats the `.dart` file completely, from top to bottom. I know it is easy to turn this off by simply going to `settings.json` file of VSCode and adding `"editor.formatOnSave": false,`

When using Android Studio, I tend to turn this feature off and do partial formatting where I choose which part of the code I want formatted and hit the keys, telling IDE to format it which is`CTRL+ALT+L` by default.

Now I wonder if I can do partial formatting in Visual Studio Code. I don't want to auto-format my dart code and I don't want to format the whole dart file in VS Code, what do I do, can I do it?

Answer (score 2):

No, there is [no partial formatting](https://github.com/dart-lang/dart_style/issues/92) as of right now.

Comment: Format Selection is available in VS Code 's Keyboard Shortcuts section. Default is CTRL +K & CTRL + F